# What is the best way to have multiple g++ toolchains installed on Debian Jessie

Tags: c++, linux, debian

I'm pretty new to linux, and I want to have installed multiple toolchains versions on my machine for testing purposes, I've read many documents on the internet refering to how to install test/experimental/unstable packages to get very new compilers packages (i.e. g++-6), but after setting Debian to find packages from test/experimental/unstable channels and install g++-6 my machine crashed, so as a new Linux user I would like to get your help to understand what is the recommended way of doing this, in my case I would like to have an easy way of testing my code against g++ (4.9, 5 and 6).

On Windows I used to download a zip package from a daily build version of mingw including g++ 5 or 6 and just setted the IDE to look for the toolchain in each folder, is that possible on Linux?

Answer (score 0):

Mixing up stable/testing/unstable branch of debian is not easy and i wouldn't recommend to do it. What you could do is to download diractly the tarball, or clone the cvs and compile the compiler on your own, having each version in their own directory.

The different releases can be found [here](ftp://ftp.fu-berlin.de/unix/languages/gcc/releases/), for example.